# trouble finding inflection point in concavity problem

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the concavity for $f(x)=x(x+1)^3$ The answer says concave down from -1 to -0.5. I found -1 as a point, but I'm having trouble figuring out how they found the -0.5.

Comment: What method did you use to get -1?  If you use the second derivative = 0, then you should get both -1 and $-\frac{1}{2}$ as roots.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first note that this graph is a quartic because

$$f(x)=x(x+1)^3=x[(x+1)(x^2+x+1)]=x(1+3x+3x^2+x^3)=x+3x^2+3x^3+x^4.$$

Now let us take the first derivative:

$$f'(x)=4x^3+9x^2+6x+1.$$

We take the second derivative to get the range of an inflection either concave up or down:
$$f''(x)=12x^2+18x+6.$$

Then we find the zeros of $f''(x)$:
$$12x^2+18x+6=0$$
$$6(2x^2+3x+1)=0$$
$$2x^2+3x+1=0$$
$$(2x+1)(x+1)=0$$
$$x=\boxed{-\frac{1}{2},-1}$$

Here is a graph:

[image]